# Error when trying to add SendGrid add-on for Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

Trying to add SendGrid functionality to my heroku rails app by running `heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter` from my app's directory, but getting an error message each time:

> Error Provisioning User - Whitelabel domain could not be located when creating customer

I'm also getting the exact same error when trying to add SendGrid Starter add-on directly through the Heroku web interface for my app.

My heroku account does have a credit card on file, so that shouldn't be the issue. This heroku app is on the free heroku tier, but I believe all the add-ons are supposed to be supported even for free heroku apps.

Has anyone run into this before? If so, any pointers on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It just worked. I believe it may have been the result of temporary service outage on the part of SendGrid (even though their system status pages indicated all services were up and running).

Sorry for the false alarm.